# Как поменять режим открытия файла, если не знаешь его имени?

Tags: c, файлы

Допустим, есть функция, которая принимает указатель на `FILE` Прототип может быть такой:

```
void func (FILE * inFile);
```

К примеру, мне нужно прочитать содержимое `inFile`, но я не знаю его имени, есть только указатель на структуру (в рамках этой отдельной функции). Можно ли поменять режим открытия файла не зная его имени? Или вытащить из структуры имя и передать в fopen уже его? Что-то типа этого:

```
void func (FILE * inFile){
inFile = fopen(inFile.name, "r");
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на функцию [`freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen). Если передавать в нее в качестве имени файла нулевой указатель - то она переоткрывает файл, переданный ей в виде `FILE*`.